# Upload file in Stripes, how to use DefaultMultipartWrapperFactory

Tags: file-upload, nullpointerexception, stripes

I'm trying to develop a small Stripes project that allows the user to uoload files, the basic implementation of the ActionBean looks like so:

```
public class UploadActionBean extends BaseActionBean{

private FileBean fileBean;

private final String fileUpload="/WEB-INF/jsp/file-upload.jsp";

public void setFileBean(FileBean fileBean){

    this.fileBean=fileBean;
}

public FileBean getFileBean(){

    return this.fileBean;
}

@DefaultHandler
public Resolution goToFile(){

    return new ForwardResolution(fileUpload);
}

public Resolution upload() throws IOException{

    System.out.println(fileBean.getFileName());

    fileBean.getContentType();

    fileBean.getSize();

    fileBean.save(new File("/Users/enricoiorio/Desktop"));

    return new ForwardResolution(fileUpload);
}
```

}

As i said is very simple, the jsp is like this, also very simple:

```
 <s:form beanclass="stripesbook.action.UploadActionBean" enctype="multipart-form/data">

<s:file name="fileBean"/>

<s:submit name="upload" value="upload"/>
```

The app seems to deploy correctly, the app starts with no problem but as soon as i click on upload i get the following exception:

```
net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesRuntimeException: Could not construct a MultipartWrapper for the current request.
```

which arrives from a nullPointerException:

```
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.multipart.DefaultMultipartWrapperFactory.wrap(DefaultMultipartWrapperFactory.java:151)
```

I understand that i have to use the wrap() method of the DefaultMultipartWrapperFactory class, but how?
I'm struggling trying to find a documentation that explains that but no results, any advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you're simply missing [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).  Try adding it to your classpath and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Lucas thx for the great Advice! i need that indeed plus commons-io the action bean throws now a FileNotFoundException in: fileBean.save(new File("/Users/myname/Desktop")) because is a directory, not a file, but i though that the File class could also write the file to a given pathname using this constructor: public File(String pathname), so basically i assume that the constructor write the file on top of an already existing file, that could be done with text but how about this when uploading a picture?

Comment: Close - you could ask the fileBean for the incoming filename (fileBean.getFileName()) and append it to your directory.. new java.io.File("/foo/bar/"+fileBean.getFileName())

Comment: Also about already existing files, you can construct it first and use java.io.File.exists() and if it doesn't, make your save() call

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same problem.
Got resolved by adding init param in stripes Filters.

```java
<init-param>
  <param-name>MultipartWrapper.Class</param-name>
  <param-value>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.multipart.CommonsMultipartWrapper</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: hi @useruser1929841 , thx for the reply, but i have dropped Stripes as is no longer supported.

Comment: Not true. Just quietly working. There is a v1.7. Asynchronous support added in a number of core features. The IRC channel is active too.